# Architecture for sending and receiving recurring information every x seconds/minutes

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, rest, websocket, architecture

I work with a mobile application that sends data (latitude/longitude) through a recurring GET request every certain time; 30 seconds, 1 minute, 5 minutes, etc., very small intervals as if it were a SENSOR, and this data is sent towards the Backend and after receiving the data from the request, this data must be displayed on screen.

My problem, is that my current architecture is a Service Oriented Architecture (SOA), so I am making an http request every time, the problem, there are hundreds of users and hundreds of requests every seconds/minute. Taking SOA is a mistake right?

Looking for alternatives, I came across an event-driven architecture (event-driven architecture), would this be the best? But it involves microservices issues, etc. I fall here, and I don't have a lot of knowledge...
Any suggestions or ideas on how to best approach it? SOA is a mistake? I need some guidance.

Comment: Why do you think SOA might be not suited for your use case?

Comment: You should write this question in https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't stress too much on the name of the architecture because Event-driven architecture implies that all the communication happens via events generated in the system. Fantastic on paper, but hard to implement correctly.

My approach would be loosely based on a microservice architecture that makes use of a message broker (kafka, rabbitmq, etc.), with one service that receives the GPS data (optionally add some contextual information, received date, device id, ...) and send it to the broker, and another service that process the GPS data and save it to a database (cluster).

In isolation, what I've described is similar to Event-driven architecture. Services are decoupled, and they interact via events, but as this is a piece of your application it wouldn't be wise to force this pattern for all other components.

Some tips that might help you down the line:

- Think about the deployment first; use containers if you can. Start with docker-compose to set up a single instance of all your services and then scale it up using docker swarm. This simplifies handling the microservices deployment.
- Not everything has to be a microservice; you can start feature by feature and integrate this pattern as you see fit. Microservices, SOA, Event-driven are more suggestions than a pattern that you apply blindly.
- Embrace asynchronous communication as it helps you to deal with scalability (you can change/scale one part of the communication without needing to change the other) and reliability (it's easier to deal with services that are not available, handle peak load).